# TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfSecret' of undefined at Object.handle - using Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, csrf, passport.js

I am making a simple web app, and trying to add authentication. Everything was working fine (separately) until I tried to merge the authentication pages with the app, and received this error message:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfSecret' of undefined at
>   Object.handle(C:Project\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\csurf\index.js:46:29)..."

Here is the code in the app.js, perhaps one of you will see where the root of the problem is.

```
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = {};
  req.db.tasks = db.collection('tasks');
  next();
})
app.locals.appname = 'Name of App'
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var passport = require('passport');

var routes = require('./routes');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongoskin.db('connection works perfectly to my mongolab account', {safe:true});

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');


mongoose.connect(configDB.url); 

require('./config/passport')(passport); 

app.configure(function() {


    app.use(express.logger('dev')); 
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); 

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.csrf());

    app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public', compress: true }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals._csrf = req.session._csrf;  //THIS COULD BE THE SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM
        return next();
    })

    app.use(app.router);


    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'Bigsecretscretsecret' })); 
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); 
    app.use(flash()); 

});


require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); 


app.listen(port);
console.log('Go to' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Express.js 4.x the Connect Middleware has been broken out into individual modules.  Make sure you install:

`$ npm install --save express-session`
&
`$ npm install --save cookie-parser`

Add to your **app.js** file:

```
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');

    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }})
```

Check out the docs [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)